# Preformatted white space inside equation

Tags: math-mode, indentation

I am trying to generate an equation that looks like:

```
∃x∀y
    if P(x, y) then
        multiline
        formula
    else
        another
        formula
```

I can't use verbatim be cause I need access to math characters and if I use align:

```
&\exists x\forall y&&
&&if\ P(x, y)\ then&
&&&multline
&&&formula
...
```

I end up with:

```
∃x∀y
    if P(x, y) then
                   multiline
                   formula
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \MoveEqLeft
\exists x\forall y  \\
    &   \text{if } P(x, y) \text{ then}         \\
    &   \quad\begin{multlined}[t]
          \framebox[0.5\linewidth]{first line}  \\
          \framebox[0.6\linewidth]{last line}
        \end{multlined}  \\
    &   \text{else} \\
    &   \quad\begin{multlined}[t]
          \framebox[0.5\linewidth]{first line}  \\
          \framebox[0.6\linewidth]{last line}
        \end{multlined}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```